# Partial update with micro services and roles

Tags: java, spring, rest, jakarta-ee, web

Which way should I structure my REST api endpoints if I have to do partial updates and need to be authenticate against roles.

**Scenerio #1**

Admin role can update every field of record so I create endpoint

- `/updateAll`       *accepts full object*
- `/updateNameAndDescription`  *accepts only name and description*
- `/updatePrice`     *accepts only price*

this allows me to to separate based on functionality and i can protect the endpoints based on what roles can update it.

**Scenerio #2**

I just have one endpoint `/resource` I accept a POST or a PATCH with the object in the body. inside the application I will have code that will determine if the current user has permission to perform the update on the fields sent.

Answer (score 0):

For starters if you are putting verbs (update) in your URL then what you are build is more RCP (which is fine) than REST - the strict adhere-ants will knock you with the distinction though.

You can define your own [JSON] schema for doing a PATCH that allows for only overriding a single field of a resource, or checkout some "standards" like JSON Patch - [JSON Patch RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902).